# Insert content into <title> head tag with function

Tags: php, functions, title

Is there a hook available that lets you append or prepend text to the `<title>` tag in the head?

I've seen lots of posts about customizing the `<title>` tag, but they all involve manually adding a function inside the `<title>` tag. I'm looking to modify it with a hook if possible so it can be easily turned on/off in a functions.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is modified with filters, not hooks.

To modify the <title>, use [wp_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) filter

Example:

```
  add_filter('wp_title', 'set_page_title');

  function set_page_title($orig_title) { 
    return 'Modified ' . $orig_title;
  }
```

Comment: Right, thanks - I thought this was to modify the title of the post. Any pointers on how to prepend something the title using this filter?

Comment: @jtotheh I've added usage example

Comment: Cheers, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Got this to work (thanks), but it changes the on-page titles when wp_title() is used elsewhere, and not just the `<title>` tags in the `<head>` - is there a filter to ONLY edit the `<title>` content?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's [`wp_title`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L608)